# Do I have the right understanding of the web app architecture? HTML5 front end, Java back end, and JSON binding

Tags: java, mysql, json, html, web-applications

I am building a web application that has an HTML5/JavaScript front end and a Java back end. I will be taking JSON objects and storing them in a MySQL database.

At the moment, I have an elementary understanding of how everything fits together.

If you could look over my outline below and point out any errors in my architecture & my understanding of this architecture, that would be very helpful. I am very new to this, so I have a hard time describing various components with proper jargon. Please correct me if I mislabel anything!

**Front End**

HTML5/JavaScript. Creates JSON objects to be sent to the server. Receives the same from the server.

**Back End**

1. Web Service (Jersey/Jackson) - Converts JSON to a Java object and vice versa.
2. Data Layer (Spring/Hibernate) - ORM: converts Java object to a format compatible with relational database and vice versa.
3. MySQL Database - stores converted JSON objects for retrieval.

One additional question:

- As I understand it, Jersey is an implementation of JAX-RS. What exactly is the relationship between Jersey and Jackson? Is Jackson simply an "add-on" that allows Jersey to serialize JSON objects into Java objects and vice versa?

Thank you very much for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack looks pretty right on.

Jersey is the framework that allows you to create web services and Jackson serializes and deserializes objects to/from JSON.

Jackson can work independently of Jersey, so you would want to use Jackson for any type of JSON serialization/deserialization.

The one note I would mention is that you wrote several times that you'd store converted JSON objects in MySQL. This is conceptually correct, but realize that one JSON object might decompose into data that should be spread across many tables. This often happens - that you need to read data from various places in MySQL and compose one JSON object.

You're definitely on the right track though - and it seems you've picked best of breed for technologies.